# Differences running a program from C:\Windows vs. C:\Windows\system32

Tags: windows-server-2008

Calling a program in windows prompt by absolute path from `C:\Windows` directory is working, but calling this program from `C:\Windows\System32` gives me errors.

- `C:\Windows>D:\pathtoexe\program.exe` --> OK
- `C:\Windows\System32>D:\pathtoexe\myprogram.exe` --> Terminates without doing it's task

The program reads a configuration file from the current directory. The configuration file exists in both (Windows and System32) directories. If I delete the file from the Windows directory then calling the program from the Windows directory terminates with the same error as if I call it from the System32 directory. There should be no file access problems:

- `C:\Windows>type config.ini`--> OK
- `C:\Windows\system32>type config.ini` --> OK

The same program with same configuration file on Windows Server 2003 is working for both directories!

How do I debug why it won't run from system32 on 2008?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are on a 64-bit OS, and `program.exe` is a 32-bit program.

If that is true, put the configuration file into the `windows\syswow64` directory. This is what appears to a 32-bit process as `system32`.

Due to the way Windows starts processes, they do not directly inherit their working directory, but perform the equivalent of a `cd` during startup. Hence the 32-bit process, started in the 64-bit system directory, actually ends up in the 32-bit system directory (called `syswow64` in a 64-bit cmd or Explorer).

Comment: Yes, it's all true what you say! Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your app is sensitive to which directory it is run in due to expecting certain files- configuration files, maybe dlls or third party exes- from the current directory. I would suggest using pstools procmon to determine the.exact files being accessed.

This may also be a 32 vs 64 bit problem. Procmon will show this as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will upvote your answer after my 15rep limit.